# Why wont filestream write whitespaces into files cpp?

Tags: c++, file

i have a cpp code

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<string>

  using namespace std;
  int main()
 {
    string s,s1;
    ofstream f("new.txt");
     cin>>s;
     f<<s;
    f.close();
    ifstream f1("new.txt");
    while(!f1.eof())
    {
     f1>>s1;
     cout<<s1;
    }
 return 0;

  }
```

if i give the input string as "MAGICAL STRING WITH SPACES" . The ofstream object only writes "MAGICAL" into the textfile, what do i do to write and read whitespaces from string variables into an output file stream ?

Comment: You may want to tell `cin` not to skip whitespaces by using [noskipws](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws)

Answer (score -2):

This is because you use cin.
Try getline() instead!

```
string newArgument = "";
getline(cin, newArgument);
```

Comment: cin can do this. Don't recommend `gets` as it is deemed "unsafe to use".

Comment: cin can do this too. the problem isnt with the iobuffers, but the filebuffer objects, not being able to read whitespaces . what do i do ?